# instanceof fails but isInstance() and isAssignableFrom() work?

Tags: java

I have some parameter `Class<? extends JsonAPIDataObject> responseClass` and when I try this `if(responseClass instanceof ThisClass)` where `ThisClass` implements `JsonAPIDataObject`, it keeps failing saying incompatible types?

edit:

```
MyClass.class.isAssignableFrom(responseClass.getClass())
MyClass.class.isInstance(responseClass.getClass())
```

both dont work, I have tried without .getClass().

Comment: Show the code. With only the description you provide, it is impossible to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: `instanceof` is _not_ suitable to be used with reflective capital-C `Class` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x instanceof Y` only compiles if the compile-time type of `x` is compatible with `Y`. For example, the code below doesn't compile because no `String` is a `Number`.

```
String str = "Foo";
System.out.println(str instanceof Number);
```

In your case, `responseClass` is a [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html), not a `ThisClass` so

```
responseClass instanceof Class
```

compiles, and gives `true`, whereas

```
responseClass instanceof ThisClass
```

doesn't compile. You should use `isInstance`.

Comment: thanks I will use isInstance

Comment: I actually can't get it to work with isInstance or isAssignableFrom. I have tried MyClass.class.isAssignableFrom(responseClass.getClass()) and a few other variations, only == is working for me...

Comment: What are you trying do? Are you trying to find if the class represented by `responseClass` is a subclass of `ThisClass` or a superclass?

Comment: responseClass being passed in is MyClass.class, MyClass.class extends JsonAPIDataObject, responseClass can also be something else, so I want to check if it is a specific instance of JsonAPIDataObject being MyClass... basically I want to see if the MyClass.class being passed in is equivalent to MyClass.class

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what you mean. `MyClass.class` is never a specific instance of `JsonAPIDataObject`. `MyClass.class` is an instanceof `Class`.

Comment: If you want to check if two `Class` objects represent the exact same class, you can just use `==`.